# How to create CREATE VIEW INVOICE_V in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some queries in SQL relating to Pine Valley Furniture System. Here is my query:

```
CREATE VIEW INVOICE_V AS
  SELECT CUSTOMER_T.CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_T.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS,
         ORDER_T.ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_T.PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_LINE_T.ORDERED_QUANTITY,
              FROM CUSTOMER_T, ORDER_T, PRODUCT_T, ORDER_LINE_T
         WHERE CUSTOMER_T.CUSTOMER_ID = ORDER_T.CUSTOMER_ID
           AND ORDER_T.ORDER_ID = ORDER_LINE_T.ORDER_ID AND (PRODUCT_T.PRODUCT_ID = ORDER_LINE_T.PRODUCT_ID),

CREATE VIEW ORDER_TOTALS_V AS
SELECT PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT, SUM(STANDARD_PRICE*ORDERED_QUANTITY) TOTAL
  FROM INVOICE_V GROUPBY PRODUCT_ID;
```

[image]

Here is output and the error in result of this query.

> sql command not properly ended

[image]

Comment: `GROUP BY` instead of `GROUPBY`.

Comment: invalid identifier   *STANDARD_PRICE* ...........?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove 2 extra commas at the end of query and select-list:

```
CREATE VIEW INVOICE_V AS
SELECT 
   CUSTOMER_T.CUSTOMER_ID, 
   CUSTOMER_T.CUSTOMER_ADDRESS,
   ORDER_T.ORDER_ID, 
   PRODUCT_T.PRODUCT_ID, 
   ORDER_LINE_T.ORDERED_QUANTITY
FROM CUSTOMER_T, ORDER_T, PRODUCT_T, ORDER_LINE_T
WHERE CUSTOMER_T.CUSTOMER_ID = ORDER_T.CUSTOMER_ID
  AND ORDER_T.ORDER_ID = ORDER_LINE_T.ORDER_ID 
  AND PRODUCT_T.PRODUCT_ID = ORDER_LINE_T.PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: adding 1 comma at the end(to run sql statement) solves the  problem

Comment: ; or / in new line, but not comma :)

Comment: they are just command separators. You can also just select your command and run only selected